# AWS RDS goes 100% with number of DB connections

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-rds

I have deployed a Laravel 4.2 based project on AWS.

I am facing an issue, when there is a load on my site RDS touches 100% CPU utilization.

For example, last time we have a load when there were 422 DB connections.
The strange part is at the same time Write IOPS and Read IOPS are just normal, slow query logs are fine.

I need a direction, how to debug this issue. I want to know which thing is causing high CPU utilization.

Thanks

Comment: well you have 422 db connections, that is a lot and you didnt say anything regarding your system memory or number of procesors. Anyways your question is [**off topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Optimize your database (indexes, etc.). Add a caching layer in front of your database (Redis). Place a CDN in front of your entire site. If your app is write-heavy then you might implement some sort of queueing system (SQS) to control the number of concurrent DB updates.